# KNN Classifier Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn

I am currently using the scikit learn module in order to help with a crime prediction problem.  I am having an issue batch coding the entire Dataframe that I have with the knn.predict method.

How can I batch code the entire two columns of my Dataframe with the knn.predict() method in order to store in another Dataframe the output?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

knn_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/helenapunset/Desktop/knn_dataframe.csv")

# x is the set of features 
x = knn_df[['latitude', 'longitude']]

# y is the target variable 
y = knn_df['Class']

# train and test data 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)

# training the data 
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)

# test score was approximately 69% 
knn.score(x_test,y_test)

# this is predicted to be a safe zone 
crime_prediction = knn.predict([[25.787882, -80.358427]])
print(crime_prediction)
```

In the last line of the code I was able to add the two features I am using which are latitude and longitude from my Dataframe labeled knn_df. But, this is a single point I have been searching through the documentation on a process for streamlining this knn prediction for the entire Dataframe and cannot seem to find a way to do this. Is there somehow a possibility of using a for loop for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the new set to be predicted is 'knn_df_predict'. Assuming same column names,try the following lines of code :

```
x_new = knn_df_predict[['latitude', 'longitude']] #formating features
crime_prediction = knn.predict(x_new) #predicting for the new set
knn_df_predict['prediction'] = crime_prediction #Adding the prediction to dataframe
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was simpler than I expected, but nonetheless I could not figure it out. I appreciate your help so much!